# how to adding color in input type date in html

Tags: html

i make Html Input with the following code :

```
<input type="date" name="tgl" value="<?=$tgl?>" required="required" />
```

in my date picker I want to add color to certain days like gray colors on current day. please see the image. there is gray on cunrrent day.

[image]

> how to add color on another day in html ?

Comment: use custom date-picker instead of using in-build date-picker

Comment: It doesn't seem like it's possible.

Comment: so the simplest way is to use jquery ?